# CloudFormation keeps throwing InvalidBucketAclWithBlockPublicAccessError for my S3 bucket template's deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

### Goal

Create an S3 bucket that my service is going to write images to and anyone is going to be able to read the image from because I am going to show the image on my service's web page.

### Problem

So I have a pretty generic (I think) template for an S3 bucket that should allow anyone to read objects inside it:

```
 SomeS3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: "some-bucket-name"
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      OwnershipControls:
        Rules:
          - ObjectOwnership: BucketOwnerPreferred # without it it complains about ownership being set to BucketOwnerEnforced
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: "AES256"
            BucketKeyEnabled: false
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
          - AllowedHeaders:
              - "*"
            AllowedMethods:
              - "PUT"
              - "POST"
              - "DELETE"
              - "GET"
            AllowedOrigins:
              - "*"
```

An attempt to deploy this template always results in an error like this: `Bucket cannot have public ACLs set with BlockPublicAccess enabled (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidBucketAclWithBlockPublicAccessError)`

Tried creating a stack from the AWS Console and with `aws-cli/2.6.4 Python/3.9.11 Linux/5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off`.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Tried adding:

```
PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: false
        BlockPublicPolicy: false
        IgnorePublicAcls: false
        RestrictPublicBuckets: false
```

But that didn't help either.

Also tried setting `ObjectOwnership` to `ObjectWriter`, checked the `BlockPublicAccess` configuration on my AWS account level. Nothing points me to the root cause of the issue.

Comment: "checked the BlockPublicAccess configuration on my AWS account level" - and what did you find? "Tried adding `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration`" - adding where, how? What exactly happen? Any new errors? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon has recently begun rolling out a change to how new buckets are created, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html

> For new buckets created after this update, all S3 Block Public Access settings will be enabled, and S3 access control lists (ACLs) will be disabled. These defaults are the recommended best practices for securing data in Amazon S3. You can adjust these settings after creating your bucket.

You need to add the `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration`, as well as set `ObjectOwnership` to `ObjectWriter` - that you've got under control - and at the same time ensure that you do not have the `AccessControl` set initially. `AccessControl` can only be modified *after* the bucket has been created.

Answer (score 4):

As @therightstuff explained I have fixed it by this way:

```
SomeS3Bucket:
  Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
  Properties:
    BucketName: "some-bucket-name"
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
      BlockPublicAcls: false
      BlockPublicPolicy: false
      IgnorePublicAcls: false
      RestrictPublicBuckets: false
    OwnershipControls:
      Rules:
        - ObjectOwnership: ObjectWriter
SomeS3AccessPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket:
      Ref: SomeS3Bucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Principal: '*'
          Action:
            - s3:GetObject
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket-name/*
```

Comment: Can you explain why you stopped using an AccessControl of PublicRead?  I'm running into the same issue (calling the API directly) where I just want to use a canned ACL of public-read and I'm attempting to set this AFTER creating the bucket with "objectowner" and then setting all 4 "block public access" settings to false.  AWS claims BlockPublicAccess is still enabled even though it isn't (confirmed via UI)

Comment: @BradWood see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045067/2860309 above for the explanation :)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer the question I asked, which was why they changed from PublicRead to some more complex ACL rule.  I already read and understood the answer you linked to and the reason it wasn't working turned out to be a mistake on my part.  I asked this question at first because I thought perhaps it was key to making it work.  And the question still stands, for what it's worth.