# Confusing documentation from Python Boto3 to create bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

As per the Request Syntax in below link, we can pass ACL parameter to create_bucket method with ACL as 'public-read'.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/create_bucket.html

but when I pass it giving the error as

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidBucketAclWithBlockPublicAccessError) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Bucket cannot have public ACLs set with BlockPublicAccess enabled

If the "public-read" can raise that error, why it mentioned about that option in the documentation? We can simply call "put_public_access_block" and then "put_bucket_acl" methods right?

Below is code sample of what I tried

```
def create_bucket(bucket_name, acl):
    bucket = boto3.client('s3')

    response = bucket.create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        ObjectOwnership='BucketOwnerPreferred',
        ACL=acl,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={
            'LocationConstraint':'us-west-1',

        }
    )

create_bucket('sample_bucket', 'public-read')
```

**Account level setting for block public access**
[image: Account level setting for block public access]

Comment: Please check the attached screenshot, it is turned off only to block public access

Comment: I think S3 is now defaulting BPA on bucket creation, regardless of account-level BPA setting, so you may have to provide an override PublicAccessBlockConfiguration, hopefully at the same time as indicating the ACL of public-read in the same call to create_bucket. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76026251).

Comment: I see that post but PublicAccessBlockConfiguration is not available to be passed to create_bucket method in Python boto3

Comment: Raised an issue here to the Boto3 team

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3775

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is in accordance with the design of Amazon S3 and its security best practices.

The documentation you referred to mentions the 'public-read' option for the ACL parameter because it represents one of the possible ACL configurations that can be used with S3 buckets. However, it's important to note that the 'public-read' ACL is incompatible with Block Public Access settings.

Comment: so this is a possible configuration but not to directly call the create_bucket method with ACL value as "public-read"?

Comment: Hi @user2225190, the combination of both `public-read` and `Block Public Access` settings is not going to yield a successful bucket creation. You will have to pick which one suits your needs. Do you mind sharing more about the business objective you were trying to solve?

Comment: I want to chose public-read without blocking public access but I want to do it with create_bucket method only. Not only business need, but even with the code I shared in question also not working